# How to add segments in a lollipop chart ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, segment

Here's my initial barchart code:

```
Full %>%                  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(POS, -Iconicity), y = Iconicity, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() + # color-blind compatible colors
  theme_minimal() + xlab("POS")
```

Which creates this lovely chart:

[image: the barchart]

So I wanted to turn this into a lollipop chart to make it look neater and more modern, and this is the code I used:

```
Full %>%                  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(POS, -Iconicity), y = Iconicity, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(size=3, stat = "summary", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=POS, 
                    xend=POS, 
                    y=0,
                    yend=Iconicity)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + # color-blind compatible colors
  theme_minimal() + xlab("POS")
```

However of course that does not add enough segments to the right places and I can't seem to work out how to change to code. What I'm left with is this:

[image: catastrophic lollipop chart attempt]

I'm still quite a novice at R clearly so forgive me

Comment: could you explain a little bit more about what you want the final figure to look like - 'lollipop chart ' is a little big vague. Could you also please use the dput() function to show us what your data looks like. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is coming from the fact you summarise your `geom_point` and not `geom_segment` and you are using `position_dodge` in `geom_point`.

Without a reproducible example of what is `Full`, it is hard to be sure of the answer to your question, but maybe you can try to summarise your values outside of `ggplot` and apply the same `position_dodge` to every `geom`:

```r
Full %>%  
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Iconicity = mean(Iconicity, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(POS, -Iconicity), y = Iconicity, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(size=3,position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=POS, 
                   xend=POS, 
                   y=0,
                   yend=Iconicity), position = position_dodge(0.9) ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + # color-blind compatible colors
  theme_minimal() + xlab("POS")
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please provide a reproducible example of what is your `Full` Dataset (see this link: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))